# Regex to not match numbers followed by a certain character

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a regular expression I use to get house numbers from street addresses.

```
\d+([a-z -A-Z]+)?
```

This works fine for addresses like `Fake Street 123` and `Fake Street 123a`. But now I came accross an address like `2. Fake Street 123` and of course the expression matches `2.` and not `123`. How can I alter the expression to not match digits that are followed by a `.` (ie `23. Fake Street 123a` shouldn't match the `23.` but the `123a`)?

Comment: It is not quite clear since `([a-z -A-Z]+)?` is an *optional* subpattern, and it does not restrict the right-hand side context for the digits. *What is an **obligatory** context for the digits?* Note you have a range between a space (32) and `A` (65) than actually matches more than letters and space.

Comment: Can't you just keep your regex and use the last match if multiple matches are found?

Comment: sorry but you require 23. and 123a?

Comment: this might be helpful [**\b(?:\d+(?!\.)[a-zA-Z]?)\b**](https://regex101.com/r/5QLKsg/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other good answers, explaining how to approach your problem of finding the right number. Regarding the question

> Regex to not match numbers followed by a certain character

```
\d+($|[^\.\d])
```

Matches a number (at least one digit) which is either the end of string or followed by a non-digit character that is also not a `.`

Answer (score 2):

If you can be sure that an address always contains at least one letter before the number, you could use

```
[^0-9]+(\d+([a-z -A-Z]+)?)
```

and then get the number by accessing Match.Groups[1] (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right you like to have the last part of the string which starts with a number followed by optional characters (like "a").

The following Regex did match all your test-cases:

```
\d*.$
```

It scans for a number followed by anyhting else at the end of the string ($)

Comment: You potentially match `.` with the last digit of the number or with any character that's not even remotely related to a number. Using `$` for end of string matching is good, but I'd be more verbose on the part before. For example with `\d+[a-zA-Z]?$`

Comment: That's right. If we know more about the expected and invalid formats one can improve the regex. This is just the minimal approach for the given test-cases (TDD :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to capture the last numbers of the string you can use the end anchor ($).

```
 (\d+.*)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/uWrPel/2

This regex will check for a space followed by any digits and optional letters at the end of the  string. (Note that i have a space before the capturing group to be sure to separate the numbers from the text)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one and let me know if you have any queries.

```
@"( [0-9]{1,})"
```